# Retrieve parts of jquery response to populate inputs and selects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I send a jQuery request (incorporating a business_id) to a php file to retrieve all values in the database to populate the fields and selects that are in my form and correspond to this id. However, how am I able to retrieve the response from the database in pieces? So that I can provide the fields and selects that are in the form with the values from the database. My javascript function looks as follows:

```
businessselect: function(){

    $('#busselect').change(function() {
        opt = $(this).val();

        if (opt=="new_bus") {

            location.reload();

        }
        else
        {
            businessid = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");

            $.ajax({
             url : "businessdata.php",
             method : "post",
             data : "business_id="+businessid,
             success: function(response) { 
                 $("#uitgevoerd_door_naam").val(response);
             }
         });
        }
    });
},
```

My businessdata.php looks as follows:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "brandveiligheid");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
   exit();
}

 if($_POST)
 {

   $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from form WHERE ID ='$_POST[business_id]'");
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['uitgevoerd_door_naam'];
    echo $row['hoev_gev_stof_score'];
   }

}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
$("#uitgevoerd_door_naam").val() == $row['uitgevoerd_door_naam'];
$("#hoev_gev_stof_score").val() == $row['hoev_gev_stof_score'];
```

etc.....

Comment: Thnx for your comment Deep, but when I try to do so I get an error: Left side of assignment is not a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

Use json encode:

function:

```
businessselect: function(){

    $('#busselect').change(function() {
        opt = $(this).val();

        if (opt=="new_bus") {

            location.reload();

        }
        else
        {
            businessid = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");

            $.ajax({
             url : "businessdata.php",
             method : "post",
             dataType: "json",
             data : "business_id="+businessid,
             success: function(response) { 

                 $("#uitgevoerd_door_naam").val(response.a); 
                 $("#riskpot_scorefield3").val(response.b); 
             }
         });
        }
    });
},
```

php file:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "brandveiligheid");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
}

if($_POST)
{

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from form WHERE ID = '$_POST[business_id]'");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo json_encode(array("a" => $row['uitgevoerd_door_naam'], "b" => $row['hoev_gev_stof_score']));
}

}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: Hmm it seems another problem arises. I want to fill a select based on val(response.b), but that does not seem to work... So text fields are filled with data but options are not selected. What can I do to fix this? I want to assign val(response.b) to a select as well. But when I try $("#riskpot3").val(response.b),, where #riskpot3 is the id of a select,, it does not select the correct option, even though it has the same value as the textfield #riskpot_scorefield3